# Proof by induction: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2i}\right)$

Tags: summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

How can the following be proved by induction? 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2i}\right)$$
I am out of ideas after practicing for a while: 
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)
$$ 
Does this involve telescoping series?

Comment: Hey, just a hint: This does not involve telescoping series.
It's a standard induction, so you just have to think about how the equations change if you insert n+1 instead of n

Comment: Why don't you prove this directly? $(1-1/2)=1+1/2-2/2$; also, $(1/3-1/4)=1/3+1/4-2/4$, etc. So, adding the RHS gives you $(1+1/2+\dots+1/2n)-(1+1/2+\dots+1/n)$.

Comment: @DJC: I have done the base case, and then tried to show that adding $\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$ to both sides does not change the equation. The problem is listed under inductions, so I am thinking it is supposed to be a practice of induction skill, which is what I am doing right now...

Comment: @inductionist: To get to the "next" sum you add $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$ and subtract $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Which means that you add ....

Comment: @user6312: I am not sure how you got there, I think I completely misunderstand the problem...

Comment: @inductionist: OK, more detail. Let $F(n)$ be the left-hand side. What is $F(n+1)$? The first term is now $\frac{1}{n+2}$, the last one is $\frac{1}{2n+2}$. Thus $F(n+1)=F(n)+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. The bit that was "added" to $F(n)$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$, which is what you need.

Comment: @user6312: ty!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n=1$, check.  note that
$$
\frac{1}{2(n+1)-1}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}=\frac{(2n+2)-(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$
(this is what changes on the rhs for $n+1$).
on the left hand side the change is
$$
\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{(2n+2)+(2n+1)-2(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$
as desired.

Comment: thanks, how exactly do you get the left side change? That's the part that gets me stumped, RHS works out pretty well.

Comment: @inductionist You don't need to perform any magic or pull anything out of a hat - see my answer. There the induction reduces to the trivial induction that a function that does not change, i.e. $\rm\:f(n+1)\ =\ f(n)\:,\ $ is constant,  $\rm\ f(n)\ =\ f(1)\:.$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $  $ For $ \, f(n)=\rm RHS - LHS\ $ show $ \ f(n\!+\!1) - f(n) = 0 = f(1)$  $\overset{\rm induct}\Longrightarrow\ f(n) = f(1) = 0\,.$

**Note** $  \ f(n\!+\!1)\ =\ f(n)\ $ boils down to $ \displaystyle\ \frac{2}{2n\!+\!2} = \frac{1}{n\!+\!1}\ $ by a very simple algebraic calculation.

Note how a simple transformation reduces inductive proof to the triviality that a function on $ \,\mathbb N\,$ is constant iff its first difference vanishes, i.e. $ \ f(n\!+\!1)-f(n)\ =\ 0.\,$ The inductive proof of this boils down to equality transitivity on a *telescoping* chain of inequalities $\,f(1) = f(2) = \,\cdots\, = f(n).\,$ While it is intuitively "obvious" that a function that never changes $ \,f(n\!+\!1) = f(n)\,$ is constant $ \,f(n) = f(1)\,$ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ it does require *rigorous* proof!

Many inductive proofs aimplify when handled similarly - by transforming the problem so that the induction becomes completely trivial, e.g. that a product of terms $> 1$ is $> 1$. Often, as above, the reduced problem succumbs to a trivial telescopic proof. You can find $\,$ [many examples of telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) in my prior posts here. These methods often serve to reduce inductions to problems that have purely mechanical solution - solvable by using rote algebra with no ingenuity required (e.g. by algorithms in computer algebra systems). For example, the above problem reduces to verifying that a rational function is zero, which requires only simple mechanical polynomial arithmetic.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2051711/242) for more on the telescopic viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof without using induction:**

\begin{align}
\text{LHS}&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{n+i}\\
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac1i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac1i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac1i-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i\right)-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2i}=\text{RHS}\\
\end{align}

I hope you find it helpful.