# Prove by induction that 3 divides $n^3+2n$

Tags: induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $n^3+2n$ is divisible by 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/proof-that-n32n-is-divisible-by-3)

How can I prove by induction that for any positive integer 
$n$, $(n^3 +2n)$ is divisible by $3$?