# $n^{3} + 2n$ is divisible by $3$. Is this induction proof correct?

Tags: induction

**Question:** Prove by means of the principle of induction that for every $n ∈ N$ the
number $n^{3} + 2n$ is divisible by $3$.

### Proof

Denote "$n^{3} + 2n$ is divisible by 3" by $P(n)$. Check $P(n)$ for an arbitrary $n$, for instance $n=1$. $1^{3}+2*1=3*1$ and thus divisible by three, therefore $P(1)$ holds.

**Induction step**: Assume $P(n)$ is is true, let $n ∈ N$. Then $(n+1)^{3}+2(n+1) =(n+1)(n^{2}+2n+1)+2(n+1)=(n+1)(n^{2}+2n+3)=n^{3}+2n^{2}+3n+n^{2}+2n+3=n^{3}+2n+3(n^{2}+n+1).$

We assumed $P(n)$ holds, thus the $n^{3}+2n$ part of the induction holds. We can obviously see that $3(n^{2}+n+1)$ is divisible by 3 and that concludes the proof.

Comment: seems ok to me.

Comment: Note also that $$n^3+2n=3n+n^3-n=3n+\underbrace{n(n-1)(n+1)}_{\text{product of 3 consecutive integers}}$$ is necessarily divisible by $3$.

Comment: As you have written it, $P(n)$ is not a statement, so it can't be true or false.  (See Thomas's answer for how to fix this.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof that $n^3+2n$ is divisible by 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/proof-that-n32n-is-divisible-by-3)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a slight rewording.

### Proof

Denote the statement

> $n^{3} + 2n$ is divisible by 3

by $P(n)$. We check $P(n)$ for an  $n=1$: $1^{3}+2*1=3*1$. Thus $P(1)$ holds.

**Induction step**: Assume $P(n)$ is is true, let $n ∈ N$. Then $(n+1)^{3}+2(n+1) =(n+1)(n^{2}+2n+1)+2(n+1)=(n+1)(n^{2}+2n+3)=n^{3}+2n^{2}+3n+n^{2}+2n+3=n^{3}+2n+3(n^{2}+n+1).$

We assumed $P(n)$ holds, thus $n^{3}+2n$ is divisible by $3$. We can obviously see that $3(n^{2}+n+1)$ is divisible by 3 and that concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Well done.